# Run Powershell Script when Button is presed

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, tkinter

I have a very simple UI in Python and i want to run a Powershell Script when a Button is presed. The Problem is, that the Script is being run without pressing the button.

These are the two relevant functions:

```
def create_buttons(self):
    self.setup = tk.Button(self, text="Bot Setup", command=self.powershell_setup())
    self.setup.pack(side="top", pady = 10, padx = 10)
    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",command=self.master.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

def powershell_setup(self):
    psxmlgen = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
                         '-ExecutionPolicy',
                         'Unrestricted',
                         './setup_bot_task.ps1'], cwd=os.getcwd())
```

BTW: I am using Tkinter as a GUI Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here,

```
self.setup = tk.Button(self, text="Bot Setup", command=self.powershell_setup())
```

It must be (`command` must be a callable object):

```
self.setup = tk.Button(self, text="Bot Setup", command=self.powershell_setup)
```